# Visiting Thailand as US permanent resident

Tags: visas, international-travel, russian-citizens, us-permanent-residents

My wife is a green card holder (Russian citizenship) and we are planning to travel to Thailand this summer.

Our flight will have multiple connections at the following airports, with less than a day at each airport:

- NRT (Japan) on the way to Thailand
- HND (Japan) on the return to US
- YVR (Canada) on the return to US

Per this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Russian_citizens), it seems that Russia requires visas for both Japan and Canada, but not Thailand. Does she need to get visas for both countries if we're only there briefly for our connection flights?

Comment: To be clear here, does your itinerary involve changing between Haneda and Narita airports, or will you be staying in only one Tokyo airport each way (e.g. Haneda onward and Narita return, or vice versa)?

Comment: @gparyani just updated the post with more detailed info.

Comment: Canada has a visa exemption for green card holders.  The Wikipedia pages on visa requirements do not reflect this, but the Wikipedia page on [Canada's visa policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Canada) does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Russian citizenship and a US permanent residence:

You don't need a visa in advance to transit through Japan. If you need to change airports or stay overnight, you can request a Shore Pass from Japan immigration on arrival.

You don't need a visa to transit through Canada, but you *do* need to obtain the [eTA electronic travel authorisation](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/apply.html).

You don't need a visa to visit Thailand for a stay of 30 days or less.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in part:

> Japan (JP)
>
> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers with a confirmed onward
>   ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar
>   day. They must stay in the international transit area of the
>   airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Tokyo
>   (HND) or Osaka (KIX) with a confirmed onward ticket for a
>   flight to a third country within 72 hours. They must stay in
>   the international transit area of the airport and have
>   documents required for the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a passport and a
>   confirmed onward ticket to a third country within 72 hours can
>   obtain a Shore Pass on arrival if there are no connecting
>   flights on the same calendar day. They must:
>
> - have documents required for the next destination; and
> - have proof of sufficient funds to cover their stay; and
> - arrive at and depart from an airport or seaport located within the same group below.
> - Group A:
>     Airports: Narita (NRT), Haneda (HND), Nagoya (NGO), Niigata
>     (KIJ), Komatsu (KMQ) and Yokota (OKO).
>     Seaports: Tokyo, Yokohama, Niigata and Nagoya.
> - Group B:
>     Airports: Osaka (KIX), Nagoya (NGO) and Komatsu (KMQ).
>     Seaports: Osaka, Kobe and Nagoya.
> - Group C:
>     Airports: Fukuoka (FUK), Nagasaki (NGS), Kumamoto (KMJ),
>     Kagoshima (KOJ), Naha (OKA) and Kadena (DNA).
>     Seaports : Hakata (Fukuoka), Shimonoseki and Naha (Okinawa).
> - Group D:
>     Airport: Chitose (CTS).
>     Seaports: Tomakomai, Otaru, Hakodate and Muroran.

---

> Canada (CA)
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers with a Permanent
>   Resident/Resident Alien Card (Form I-551) issued by the USA
>   and an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA).

---

> Thailand (TH)
>
> Visa required, except for Nationals of Russian Fed. with a
>   normal passport for a maximum stay of 30 days.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Visa exempt visitors older than 12 years must hold
>     sufficient funds to cover their stay (at least THB 20,000.-
>     per person or THB 40,000.- per family).